# Class '\t3lib_cache_backend_FileBackend' not found

Tags: php, typo3

After updating TYPO3 from 4.5 to 7.6 and a PHP update from 5.3 to 5.5 I get this error in the install tool:

> **Detected Fatal Error**
>
> Class '\t3lib_cache_backend_FileBackend' not found in
>   /var/www/htdocs/typo3src/typo3_src-7.6.9/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/CacheFactory.php
>   on line 76

PHP-Version is 5.5.36. 
A new download of the TYPO3 src did not solve it.

Comment: possibilities: clear cache and remove or rename typo3temp or permission issue or check here please https://github.com/cogitatio/TYPO3v4-Core/blob/master/t3lib/cache/backend/class.t3lib_cache_backend_filebackend.php

Answer (score 1):

Check your `LocalConfiguration.php` for the missing class. You need to change it to `TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\FileBackend` or comment that line temporary to get into install tool (probably multiple lines with similar classes). Alternatively upgrade first to 6.2 and run migration wizard and then upgrade to 7.6, which should go smoother.

Answer (score 0):

The solution: it was an old extension ws_less, that still required this class. I found it by `grep FileBackend * -R` in typo3conf/ext/. 
After deactivating it in PackageStates.php everything ran smoothly.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/visol/ws_less is you need a 7.6-compatible version.

Comment: Thanks. Already switched to adx_less, which does more or less the same.